# If Statement with Foreach not iterating through foreach

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I am having an issue with my code - fairly new to PHP so any pointers would be appreciated.

I have the following code

```
foreach(findCustomAlerts($customerid) as $key=>$value){

    echo "ID : ".$rifdid = $value['Catid']."<br>";
    echo "Visits required per day : ".$visitsneeded= $value['Visits required']."<br>";
  
}

foreach(getTodaysVisits($device_id) as $rfid){
    foreach($rfid as $key=> $read){
 
        if($key ==$rifdid && $read < $visitsneeded) {  
            echo"<br>". $key." has not visited enough";
       
         }
    
    }

}
```

But it is not iterating through the foreach - it is only picking up the first values and then stopping :

```
ID: 1005
Visits required per day : 3
ID : 2089
Visits required per day : 5

2089 has not visited enough
```

This is the array that the foreach should be iterating through:

```
Array
(
    [rfid_id] => Array
        (
            [2089] => 1
            [1005] => 3
        )

)
```

I have tried putting a variable in to count the iterations like so :

```
$i = 0;

foreach(getTodaysVisits($device_id) as $rfid){
    foreach($rfid as $key[$i]=> $read){
 
        if($key[$i] ==$rifdid && $read < $visitsneeded) {  
            echo"<br>". $key[$i]." has not visited enough";
            $i++;
        }
    
    }

}
```

But it gives me the following errors :

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array 
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in
```

So not sure what the best course of action is, any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make sure what `getTodaysVisits($device_id)` returns.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the structure that you are receiving from `findCustomAlerts($customerid)` in the first for-each loop is not what you are expecting, however the warnings don't give line numbers so I could be wrong.

In your code you have a `$key` that goes unused, then a `$value` that you treat as an array.

The warning message you get tells us that you can't use a scalar (or singular) value type as an array. We then get a notice telling us that when we try to use it as an array, either the offset `'Catid'` or `'Visits required'` is unavailable, likely due to the same reason. I suspect `$value` is more likely of type integer based on the array example you've shown (1,3).

Run a `var_dump()` on the output of the `findCustomAlerts` function and I think you'll understand the issue better.